# How to update information by the click of a button?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I currently have two php files (index.php and update.php) In index.php, there is some javascript code and a button that sends a variable, called $sid, to update.php, where it is processed based on $sid. Here is the code for both index.php and update.php. I am not pasting it directly into StackOverflow, simply because of how you have to add code to your text on StackOverflow, and how JavaScript works with it's spacing hierarchy.

http://pastebin.com/fq87vvgz

Currently, when you press the button, an alert box does not pop up. If you put the PHP code in a PHP code checker, no errors appear.

Here is my code:

This is what is in **index.php**

```
<?php 
$sid = 11;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#vote').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'update.php', // Notice how this sends to update.php
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                    action : 'vote_server',
                    sid : $('#sid').data('sid')
                },
                dataType : 'JSON',
                success : function(result) {
                    if (result.xhr == 'success') {
                        alert('You bumped your server!');
                    } else if (result.xhr == 'voted_already')
                        alert('You can only bump every 24 hours!')
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="vote" value="Vote up your server">
```

This is what is contained in **update.php**

```
<?php
    define('action',$_POST['action']);
    $result = array(
        'xhr' => 'error'
    );

    if (action == 'vote_server')
    {
        $sid = (int)$_POST['sid'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $time = time();

        $dbTime = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `last_updated` FROM `servers` WHERE `id` = '$sid'"), 0); 
        $timeDiff = $time - $dbTime;
        if($timeDiff >= 86400){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `servers` SET `last_updated` = '$time' WHERE `id` = '$sid'");
            $result['xhr'] = 'success';
        }  else { $result['xhr'] = 'voted_already';  }

    }

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Is it a php/mysql/sql problem, or just a javascript/html question? Can i create a snippet that address only the question please?

Comment: Does "sid : $('#sid').data('sid')" point to a DOM element?

Comment: Josmar, I am not sure what the problem is. I am pretty sure it isn't the MySQL side of the script, but it may be, so I included that part of the script and listed it under mysql,sql. I use PHP for querying the tables as well, so I listed that too. Alfabravo, $('#sid').data('sid') is meant to point to the PHP variable $sid defined at the top of the document. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: It seems like there are a number of fault points here. It could be SQL query, it could be the javascript, it could be a number of things...

Answer (score 0):

Use query and ajax

in your index page...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".button" ).click(function() {
         var var1 = $(this).data('var1');
         var var2 = $(this).data('var2');   

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'update.php',
           data: {postedVar:var1, postedVar2:var2}, 
           success: function(data)
                {
                alert(data);                         
                }
         });
     });
});
</script>

<html>
<button class="button"  data-var1="<?php echo "this is var1"; ?>"  data-var2="<?php echo "this is var2"; ?>">Button</button>
</html>
```

On you update page...

access your vars like this

```
<?php 

var1 = $_POST['postedVar1'];
var2 = $_POST['postedVar2'];

echo var1;
?>
```

...NOT TESTED